# Adding complex HTML dynamically to div using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a webpage that list a lot of elements (movies to be specific), the HTML structure of every item is in some way large and complicated (divs, images, links, CSS class, etc).

Firstly I load 100 elements and the user have the option of load the next 100 (this is made using infinite scroll): by now, I make a AJAX petition requesting the another 100 elements and it responds with a HTML text (with all of them loaded) and I just append it to the document.

But, now I don't want to respond with the HTML text, instead of that I want to respond with the 100 elements data in a JSON (I can do that),  then, my question is: Which is the best way to add these elements to the document using Javascript?

I know that I can loop over the JSON array and construct every element, but as I said, it's a large HTML structure and I don't really want to create divs and then attach it to another div,set CSS classes, etc with Javascript, because it might get disordered,messy and very large...So, there's a way in javascript to achieve this maybe using something like templates? How can I do that? I just want to get a clean and better code.

The structure of every movie is like this (can I use it like a template?):

```
 <div data-section="movies" data-movie_id="myid" id="movie-id" class="movie anotherclass">
        <img src="myImageUrl">
        <div class="aCSSclass">
            <div class="aCSSclass">
                <div class="aCSSclass"></div>
                <div class="aCSSclass">
                    <div class="aCSSclass">
                        Movie title
                    </div>

                    <div class="details form-group">
                        <a class="aCSSclass" href="myHref">Details</a>
                        <button onclick="SomeFunction" class="aCSSclass">My button</button>
                        <div class="aCSSclass"><span class="icon star"></span><span class="aCSSclass"></span><span class="aCSSclass"></span><span class="aCSSclass"></span><span class="aCSSclass"></span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Look into the [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment).

Comment: You can either generate all manually (using dom), clone a previous movie  and change the data accordingly (jquery .clone()) or use a template library like handlebars

Comment: @juvian I like that way (cloning) in this way I can only put the structure hidden and the copy->fill it-> append it Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the javascript part? do you use innerHTML?

Comment: @pdem the Javascript part is only a ajax petition, then I receive the HTML and append it to the correspondant div.But now I want to receive a JSON not a HTML. By now it's the only thing that I have, nothing specific of the project

Comment: You may look Angular, It meets exactly your need of templating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is to make a template and then copy the node using `cloneNode()`. Append all the cloned nodes to a `documentFragment` to save time on drawing and finally append it to the page.

An approach to this:

```js
var movies = {"movie1" : { "title" : "Die Hard", "imageurl" : "example.com/image.jpg", "details" : "http://example.com", "func" : "functionname" },
             "movie2" : { "title" : "Die Hard 2", "imageurl" : "example.com/image.jpg", "details" : "http://example.com", "func" : "functionname" },
             "movie3" : { "title" : "Die Hard With 3", "imageurl" : "example.com/image.jpg", "details" : "http://example.com", "func" : "functionname" }
             };

function functionname()
{
  alert("NYI");
}

var keys = Object.keys(movies); //get the keys.
var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
{
  var tempNode = document.querySelector("div[data-type='template']").cloneNode(true); //true for deep clone
  tempNode.querySelector("div.title").textContent = movies[keys[i]].title;
  tempNode.querySelector("img").src = movies[keys[i]].imageurl;
  tempNode.querySelector("button").onclick = window[movies[keys[i]].func];
  tempNode.querySelector("a").href = movies[keys[i]].details;
  tempNode.style.display = "block";
  docFrag.appendChild(tempNode);

}
document.body.appendChild(docFrag);
delete docFrag;
```

```html
<!-- template --> 
<div style="display: none" data-type="template" data-section="movies" data-movie_id="myid" id="movie-id" class="movie anotherclass">
        <img src="myImageUrl">
        <div class="aCSSclass">
            <div class="aCSSclass">
                <div class="aCSSclass"></div>
                <div class="aCSSclass">
                    <div class="aCSSclass title">
                        Movie title
                    </div>

                    <div class="details form-group">
                        <a class="aCSSclass" href="myHref">Details</a>
                        <button onclick="SomeFunction" class="aCSSclass">My button</button>
                        <div class="aCSSclass"><span class="icon star"></span><span class="aCSSclass"></span><span class="aCSSclass"></span><span class="aCSSclass"></span><span class="aCSSclass"></span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is just an example, not based upon your actual JSON. However you can easily clone a template and then fill in the values.

Use

- document.querySelector
- document.querySelectorAll
- document.createDocumentFragment
- Element.cloneNode(bool)